# Can I hook my Wii up to an HDMI or DVI monitor?

Tags: nintendo-wii, monitor

I have a 15" TV and a 24" HD LCD flat screen monitor. I have a Wii, which is currently hooked up to the smaller TV.

Is there anything I can do to play my wii on the flatscreen? The monitor is HDMI and DVI-compatible.

And yes, I realize that I won't get HD graphics from the Wii. I just want the larger screen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it, but it's not terribly cheap. You need something like this:

[http://www.amazon.com/Pyle-PYPBHD40-Component-Converter-Support/dp/B0038P58HY](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0038P58HY)

The plug in the first answer won't get you there; it's for specific video cards that are capable of putting out component analog signals on particular pins on the DVI connector. You can't turn component video into DVI or HDMI with a passive adapter, since you have to convert the image from analog to digital.

Edit: if your monitor takes only digital and won't take analog VGA on some of the DVI pins, I don't think the Wii -> VGA -> DVI adapter route is going to help you either. There are VGA -> DVI converter boxes like the one above that take in analog VGA and put out digital DVI, but the ones I know of are super-expensive since they can handle much higher resolutions than your Wii's going to put out.

Answer (score 1):

There are currently two Wii->HDMI adapters:

Neoya Wii2HDMI:
http://www.neoya.com/shop/wii2hdmi/

Vdigi VD-W3: http://www.vdigi.com/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&page=shop.product_details&product_id=21&aff_id=3&textad_id=1&vmcchk=1&Itemid=53

There are also a "generic" Component->HDMI adapter like this one: http://www.dealextreme.com/details.dx/sku.29772

The Wii2HDMI is IMO the best option. It's much smaller than the other options, and it does not require any external power supply. I already own one, and can vouch it works perfectly.

Important: The Wii2HDMI does not perform any upscaling of the signal, so your monitor/TV will be receiving a 480i/480p signal, and not all support these. Remember to check this before making your purchase.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a Wii to HDMI adaptor, but I do know of a [Wii to VGA adaptor](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0015MISAG)

That should get you up and running for video at least.  You'll need to find a way to run the audio into your speakers (But an RCA to 1/8" in adaptor will get you there)

*Edit*

Sorry misread your post, but you can use the cable listed above, and a VGA to DVI adaptor (which usually comes with video cards, or can be picked up for a couple of bucks.)