# Connecting my Wii to my TV over HDMI

Tags: nintendo-wii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I hook my Wii up to an HDMI or DVI monitor?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6797/can-i-hook-my-wii-up-to-an-hdmi-or-dvi-monitor)

I've read a few questions about this on here about this and was wondering if anyone could confirm that this would work (before I go buy the parts I need).

So connect the Wii over a nintendo component cable:
[Nintendo Official Component Video Cable (Wii)](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Nintendo-Official-Component-Video-Cable/dp/B000JJRV90)

Then from the component to DVI:
[Dvi-I Male To 3 Rca Component Adapter](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Dvi-I-Component-Adapter-Video-Cards/dp/B001OFG2LG/ref=sr_1_cc_1?s=aps&ie=UTF8&qid=1336253491&sr=1-1-catcorr)

Then to HDMI:
[HDMI to DVI Cable](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Premium-HDMI-Cable-Gold-Metre/dp/B000GDI6FC/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1336253519&sr=8-1)

I see no reason why this wont work but I've never used a component cable setup before! I'm not looking to improve what I get on screen but my TV doesn't have a working scart input anymore!

Thanks

Comment: Since you've pointed out that this question covers the same ground as a previous question, I'm going to close it as a dupe, and try to work on getting the previous question's answer corrected.

Comment: Sure thats fine. I didn't want to dupe but I also didn't want hi-jack that other post.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, no, this won't work with the parts you've picked out.

Some of these conversions are supported - HDMI is backwards compatible with DVI, for instance.  If you already had DVI out from your device, you could connect it to an HDMI port with a passive adapter (such as the one you've listed here).  Passive adapters don't convert the video signal, they just take advantage of the fact that certain video output technologies were designed to be backwards compatible.

However, there isn't a "standard" passive DVI to Component adapter - the two technologies are largely incompatible.  The one you've selected is intended for specific models of ATI Radeon cards that are capable of transmitting component video via the DVI port, but require an adapter and some special settings to do so.  If you read the Amazon reviews, you can see a listing of the specific ATI cards it was designed for, along with some disappointed reviewers who tried and failed to do something similar to what you are doing currently.

If you must connect a component video source to an HDMI output device, you'll need what's called an "active" Component -> HDMI converter, for example [this one](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=101&cp_id=10114&cs_id=1011406&p_id=5971&seq=1&format=2).  Typically these are devices that require external power, and they are capable of converting between video standards.  However, these boxes can get costly, and the cheap ones tend to have significant signal loss or quality issues.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I found those components in the answer from here http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6797/can-i-hook-my-wii-up-to-an-hdmi-or-dvi-monitor. I wasn't too sure myself, but as I've said I've never used these before, so thanks for confirming!

Comment: @ing0, that answer on the other question appears incorrect.  You can see on the product page that it requires those specific ATI cards as I mentioned.

Comment: Yea, I didn't see that earlier! Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

The Dvi-I Male To 3 Rca Component Adapter will not work.

Component is an analog signal and HDMI (and DVI) is digital. So you cannot go from one to an other with just an adapter. You need in fact a box that is specialized in these analog/digital video conversion.
After a quick search on amazon, something like this: [http://www.amazon.com/Component-video-YPbPr-Converter-Up-scale/dp/B0016SN49Y](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0016SN49Y)

The quality of these converter can change from one model to the other so be careful when you pick one.

But I'm surprised that your TV doesn't have component.
What is the brand of your TV exactly? Some TV have some weird component ports.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check those out. I was looking to do this using some sort of official kit from nintendo but it doesn't look like they support this. My TV is a 1 generation old Samsung smart TV. It came with a cable created for their TV's to scart, but it has a incredibly bad connection (at their custom port). It works, but the slightest movement disconnects the adapter and it's not feasible. For a while I had some bluetack holding it in place but it's just rubbish!

Comment: Buying one of those boxes + the component cable is going to get expensive. I do have an old VGA box that has a scart input, I might just use that for now!

Comment: @ing0, you can't go from VGA->DVI->HDMI - you can only do one of the two conversions, and not both in a row.

Comment: What I mean is I can do Wii Scart -> VGA box -> VGA port on TV. It's just not that great quality.